# empty cart button not working to delete the cart

Tags: php, html

Trying to get this to empty  and update cart to empty after pressing button 
but it just refreshes with all items still in cart

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/header.php");
    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/connection/connection.php");
    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/definitions.php");

    $user = $_SESSION['customer_id'];
    $cart_id = $_SESSION['cart_id'];
```

thats the top of my view cart php
 here is the button

```
<a href="/cart/destroy_sessions.php"><button id="cart_empty_button">Empty Cart</button> </a>
```

and lastly here is my destoy sessions php

```
unset($_SESSION['add_to_cart']);
unset($_SESSION['product_id']);
unset($_SESSION['price']);
unset($_SESSION['quantity']);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://sales.prosourceedm.com/cart/view_cart.php'>";
```

Comment: Did you start session before unset those $_SESSION variables?

Comment: yes I just added a session_start(); but still when it refreshes the cart still there

Comment: Can you edit your question and add all your destroy_sessions.php code?

Comment: <?php
    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/connection/connection.php");
        session_start();
        $cart_id = $_SESSION['cart_id'];
        $user = $_SESSION['customer_id'];
    
    unset($_SESSION['add_to_cart']);
    unset($_SESSION['product_id']);
    unset($_SESSION['price']);
    unset($_SESSION['quantity']);
    unset($_SESSION['cart_id']);
    
?>
 <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://sales.prosourceedm.com/cart/view_cart.php'>